# Optimization of array function that calculates products

Tags: arrays, excel, function, optimization

I have the following array formula that calculates the returns on a particular stock in a particular year:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(E2=E3),H2=H3),PRODUCT(IF($E$2:E2=E1,$O$2:O2,""))-1,"")
```

But since I have 500,000 row entries as soon as I hit row 50,000 I get an error from Excel stating that my machine does not have enough resources to compute the values.

How shall I optimize the function so that it actually works?

E column refers to a counter to check the years and ticker values of stocks. If year is different from the previous value the function will output `1`. It will also output `1` when the name of stock has changed. So for example you may have values for year 1993 and the next value is 1993 too but the name of stock is different, so clearly the return should be calculated anew, and I use `1` as an indication for that.

Then I have another column that runs a cumulative sum of those `1`s. When a new `1` in that previous column is encountered I add `1` to the running total and keep printing same number until I observe a new one. This makes possible use of the array function, if the column that contains running total values (E column) has a next value that is different from previous I use my twist on SUMIF but with PRODUCT IF. This will return the product of all the corresponding running total E column values.

[image: SO24335932 question example]

Comment: Oh yes, without it its like 600k rows. Here is the link to the screenshot:http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=afh6q1&s=8

Comment: in the worst case scenario, I just have to change those fixed E2 and fixed O2 values to the new fixed values every 40k rows... But that is silly

Comment: This really sounds like something much better done in SQL.

Comment: or SAS.. but I have no time to learn those right now

Comment: I also tried to come up with VBA code for that... nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the inefficiency, I believe, is in the steady increase with row number of the number of cells that must be examined in order to evaluate each successive array formula. In row 50,000, for example, your formula must examine cells in all the rows above it.

I'm a big fan of array formulas, so it pains me to say this, but I wouldn't do it this way. Instead, use additional columns to compute, in each row, the pieces of your formula that are needed to return the desired result. By taking that approach, you're exploiting Excel's very efficient recalculation engine to compute only what's needed.

As for the final product, compute that from a cumulative running product in an auxiliary column, and that resets to the value now in column O when column P in the row above contains a number. This approach is much more "local" and avoids formulas that depend on large numbers of cells.

I realize that text is not the best language for describing this, and my poor writing skills might be adding to the challenge, so please let me know if more detail is needed.

Interesting problem, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. You are correct, that is the source of inefficiency and that is why I was thinking of resetting the column values in some way... I have now tried to copy/paste values once I have a couple correct results, I then deleted empty rows with VBA, but I still run into same problem because of the immense amount of data that needs processing./ I agree with your point in para 2, but how do I do it? I cannot think of a way... And I totally lost you in para 3, and I am not sure what auxiliary column is. Thank you.

Comment: Column D and E are acutally calculating the pieces of information I need.  Can you suggest a way as to how I can avoide using that row "build-up" there...?

Comment: I think I just did it. But what I did is very ugly. So I have a column that has a value of 1 if next year is different from current, otherwise "" (blank). Then I have another column - running sum of values in previous, if value is one, update sum by one and keep printing that number until new one is encountered, so far the same code. But then I have third column with Countif, that counts particular value from running sum, e.g. 1, or two or whatver. The max that I have in that column is 11, for 12 months. If I encounter 11 and I see 1 in column 1 then fourth column prints product of 12 months

Comment: returns. Dear me... Whole day wasted just to figure out this simple trick.. Now I think my work can proceed. Thank you everyone for the input. If you however, have more neat suggestions, please feel free.. I would still appreciate a tip on how to do this better. Thank you again.

Comment: @LemonSqueezy, re paragraph 3: yes, text isn't the way to communicate about this. Perhaps it's easier if we break the problem into parts. Let's do a running product. Start with a fresh sheet. Put zeroes in A2:A25. Then put 1 in A2, A10, and A25. In B2:B25, put numbers like you have in your Column O. Then in Column C, put a formula that retrieves the B cell if the A cell is 1, otherwise it returns the product of the cell above and the cell to its left. That's what I had in mind for a running product. What goes in column D will be C's cell in the row above if A is 1, otherwise "".

Comment: nice! I like your suggestion! What I have right now is similar but not quite. I only compute returns when I have 12 months of data available, so I miss those that are less than 12 months. The problem with having the running total is: if a different company turns up in the next row with the same year of returns, then the function will still count the returns... and that is not desirable. (i.e. it will mix up returns of different companies)

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest a really quick and [very] dirty vba? Something like the below. Obviously, have a **backup of your file** before running this. This assumes you want to start calculating from row 13.

```
Sub calculateP()

    'start on row 13, column P:
    Cells(13, 16).Select

    'loop through every row as long as column A is populated:
    Do
        If ActiveCell(1, -14).Value = "" Then Exit Do 'column A not populated so exit loop
            'enter formula:
            Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(AND(NOT(RC[-11]=R[1]C[-11]),RC[-8]=R[1]C[-8]),PRODUCT(IF(R[-11]C5:RC[-11]=R[-1]C[-11],R2C15:RC[-1],""""))-1,"""")"

        'convert cell value to value only (remove formula):
        ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value

        'select next row:
        ActiveCell(2, 1).Select
    Loop

End Sub
```

Sorry, this is *definitely* not a great answer for you... in fact, even this method could be achieved more elegantly using range... but, the quick and dirty approach may help you in the interim ??

Comment: Hello David, your response is extremely appreciated. I have tried to use VBA to clear the contents of empty cells which hold the array formula, so that only cells with numeric values and clearly formulas that output those results are left. But my Excel keeps crashing even when doing smth as simple as that... My laptop has 8 processors and still it crashes... Let me try your VBA.

Comment: my initial array function could work just fine if I could reset the fixed to relative ranges every 20k rows. So they would drop the fixed value to the current corresponding value... But my VBA is not that advanced so as to be able to do that...